# New document-button behave as the Transfer documents-button

Tags: sharepoint-2010

In an ordinary document list in SharePoint 2010 there are two buttons for adding documents: “New document” and “Transfer documents”. New document usually opens a blank word document, and Transfer documents usually gives the possibility to choose a document to add to the list.

In a document library in our environment, the New document button opens the form to upload an existing file rather then open an empty word document.

Why does this happen? Is there a setting that specifies this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens when there are no default templates, possible due to custom content types with no set default document template (word, excel, etc) pherhaps due to upgrade from SP 2007 to 2010?

Quick fix: Add document template to the custom content type and *add document* should reappear.